# How to provide the dynamic filename in addFormDataPart in android

Tags: android, okhttp

**My problem statement is to upload the image in the server along with the form parameter.
I have used okhttp.
I am passing the MediaType as "image/*".
I am using the post request.
In the addformdatapart I am passing the mandatory fields for successful execution of the request.
bodyToString is used to print the log.My code is here
I am getting the response successful if i used file.getName then the file is not saved.When I give the static filename then the image is getting saved.**

```
    public void uploadFile(){
        File file=new File(mediaPath);
        try {
            String filename="\\" +file.getName();
            final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/*");
            String url="/updateCard";
            if (preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN) != null &&
                    !preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN).isEmpty()
                    && preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.USER_ID) != null &&
                    !preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.USER_ID).isEmpty()
                    && cardId != null && !cardId.isEmpty()) {
                RequestBody req = new MultipartBuilder().
                        //addFormDataPart("accesstoken",preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN))
                        type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("userID",preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.USER_ID))
                        .addFormDataPart("cardID",cardId)
                        .addFormDataPart("personName","dh")
                        .addFormDataPart("emailID", "dh@gmail.com")
                        .addFormDataPart("logo",filename, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file)).build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(req)
                        .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
                        .addHeader("accesstoken", preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN))
                        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                        .addHeader("postman-token", "4e6f827f-0505-cefc-b26c-223866fcff41")
                        .build();

                bodyToString(request);
                //HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                //logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
              //  client.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
               //     @Override
               //     public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
              //          String credential = Credentials.basic("accesstoken",preferenceManager.getPreferenceValues(PreferenceConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN));
              //          return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
             //       }

            //        @Override
           //         public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
//                    }
          //      });


                com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                if(response!=null && response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.d("Success","Image Upload Successful");
                }

            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("External Error", "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String bodyToString(final Request request){

        try {
            final Request copy = request.newBuilder().build();
            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            copy.body().writeTo(buffer);
            return buffer.readUtf8();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            return "did not work";
        }
    }
```

So when I give filename i.e.
.addFormDataPart("logo",filename, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file)).build();
then the call will go to the server but the file will not be saved.But when I will pass the static file name then the image will get saved in the server.
For Example:
.addFormDataPart("logo","profile.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file)).build();

Comment: You should not have added the "\\".

Comment: without adding "\\" also I am not able to upload the image.

Comment: Earlier you said you were able to upload but that the file did not get saved.

Comment: basically in this line  .addFormDataPart("logo","profile.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file)).build(); instead of profile.png if i add filename or file.getname then the image is not getting uploaded.

Comment: "profile.png" is hardcoded value

Comment: If the only difference is "profile.png" replaced by file.getName() then what is the name of the file?

Comment: so basically if i give the hardcoded value then the image is been upload.But If i passed the filename.getName() then the iamge is been not uploaded.Name of the file will be dynamic.It is like user selecting an image from gallery and we need to save the image in server.

Comment: I asked you to give an example of such a file name that fails. So what is the va!ue of file.getName()?

Comment: a1112354879.jpg

Comment: MEDIA_TYPE_PNG ?

Comment: MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG=MediaType.parse("image/*");

Comment: And if you hard code that jpg file name?

Comment: then also the image is not uploaded.only the name with .png ie. hardcoded value should end with .png extension then the server is uploading the image

Comment: file.getName() + ".png"; or file.getName().replace(". jpg", ". png"); ?

Comment: If I suppose selected jpg and then replace it with png.In the server it will be stored with .png extension.Then when i want to retrieve the image it will be in png format and the image quality will go on toss